# How can I select the Nth row of a group of fields?

Tags: sql, select, filemaker

I have a very very small database that I am needing to return a field from a specific row.

My table looks like this (simplified)

```
Material_Reading Table

pointID Material_Name
123     WoodFloor
456     Carpet
789     Drywall
111     Drywall
222     Carpet
```

I need to be able to group these together and see the different kinds (WoodFloor, Carpet, and Drywall) and need to be able to select which one I want and have that returned. So my select statement would put the various different types in a list and then I could have a variable which would select one of the rows - 1, 2, 3 for example.

I hope that makes sense, this is somewhat a non-standard implementation because its a filemaker database unfortunately, so itstead of one big SQL statement doing all I need I will have several that will each select an individual row that I indicate.

What I have tried so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Material_Name FROM MATERIAL_READING WHERE Room_KF = $roomVariable
```

This works and returns a list of all my material names which are in the room indicated by the room variable. But I cant get a specific one by supplying a row number.

I have tried using LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1. Possibly not supported by Filemaker or I am doing it wrong, I tried it like this - it gives an error:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Material_Name FROM MATERIAL_READING WHERE _Room_KF = $roomVariable ORDER BY Material_Name LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
```

I am able to use ORDER BY like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Material_Name FROM MATERIAL_READING WHERE Room_KF = $roomVariable ORDER BY Material_Name
```

Comment: Unless you provide `ORDER BY` expression there is no such thing as `nth row`.

Comment: This is a filemaker database, I am using the function ExecuteSQL which accepts many of the SQL commands, but I am having a hard time finding specifically what all is supported.

Comment: Btw, the documentation, at least for v13, is [here](https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/docs/13/en/fm13_sql_reference.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MSSQL

```
 SELECT DISTINCT Material_Name 
 FROM MATERIAL_READING
 WHERE _Room_KF = 'roomVariable' 
 ORDER BY Material_Name 
 OFFSET N ROWS 
 FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY
```

where N->from which row does to start

X->no.of rows to retrieve which were started from (N+1 row)

Comment: OP asked for Filemaker.

Comment: Thank you this was basically the answer. I was able to google FETCH and OFFSET and its supported by Filemaker - the final working code is this:             SELECT DISTINCT Material_Name FROM MATERIAL_READING WHERE \"_Room_KF\" = ? ORDER BY Material_Name OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY                 not sure why FileMaker requires the "ROWS ONLY" part but it works!